# Why <script src=""> isn't working?

Tags: javascript, html

Why I cant get access to the script by src method, but when I put script inside my html file its all ok? Any ideas? I did many things like putting this script in folders etc. but now I have it in the same folder like my html site, so what's the problem? Please help me!

This is my .html file

```
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <title> HTML/CSS: układ strony www w oparciu o elementy HTML5. </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="data.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="strona">
        <header class="elementy">
         <img src="zdj/win95.png" alt="Win95" />
         <p>Najlepszy system operacyjny świata...</p>
         <div id="txt"></div>
        </header>

        <nav id="nav_gorny" class="elementy">
           <ol>
           <li class="home"><a href="index.html">Strona główna</a></li>
           <li class="system"><a href="system.html">O systemie</a></li>
           <li class="wymag"><a href="wymagania.html">Wymagania</a></li>
           <li class="galeria"><a href="galeria.html">Galeria</a></li>
           </ol>
        </nav>

        <nav id="nav_lewy" class="elementy">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Strona główna</a></li>
            <li><a href="system.html">O systemie</a></li>
            <li><a href="wymagania.html">Wymagania systemu</a></li>
            <li><a href="galeria.html">Galeria zdjęć Windows95</a></li>
            <li><a href="programy.html">Programy</a></li>
            <li><a href="autor.html">Autor</a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>


        <article>
            <section id="sekcja_gorna" class="elementy">
                <p> Wymagania sprzętowe </p>
            </section>
            <section id="sekcja_dolna" class="elementy">
                <p>
                <table style="width:100%">
                     <tr>
                        <th>Minimalne</th>
                        <th>Zalecane</th>
                     </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Procesor Intel 80386DX 16 MHz</td>
                        <td>Procesor Intel 80486DX 16 MHz</td>
                    </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>4 MB pamięci RAM (8 MB przy OSR2 i późniejsze)  </td>
                        <td>8 MB pamięci RAM (16 MB przy OSR2 i późniejsze)</td>
                    </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>50-55 MB wolnego miejsca na dysku</td>
                        <td>50-55 MB wolnego miejsca na dysku</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>VGA (640x480), 16 kolorów</td>
                        <td>SVGA (800x600), 256 kolorów</td>
                    </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>Stacja dyskietek 3½" o wysokiej gęstości</td>
                        <td>Stacja dyskietek i napęd CD-ROM</td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                </p>                
            </section>
        </article>
</br>
        <aside class="elementy">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="zdj/auto.jpg">
        </a>
        <a href="#">
        <img src="zdj/poz.png">
        </a>
        </aside>
<br />
       <center> <footer class="elementy">
           <p> Copyright © Maciej Śliwiński 4F &nbsp;<a href="kontakt.html"> Kontakt &nbsp;</a> <a href="autor.html"> Autor </a></p>
        </footer></center> 
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

And this is my .js file

```
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    "Time: " + h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Is it in the same folder.check the file name

Comment: you did not close the link tag

Comment: and there is no ending div tag too...link is void element so need not be closed but in the markup you provided there is no ending tag for div

Comment: link tag? Where exactly?

Comment: Your js file is `my .js` but your code call `data.js`. Also your js file have to be in the same folder than the HTML file. try `<script src="my.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: @user3502626 `my .js` isn't the name of the file I don't think :p

Comment: But I ended my div here: <div id="txt"></div>

Comment: Check the browser developer tools console for errors

Comment: My name of html file is wymagania.html

Comment: maybe your script has an error. press f12 key on your keyboard to see the log.

Comment: I checked, 0 errors here :(

Comment: Did you check if there's a data.js in the same directory as the html file (Geeky's first suggestion)?

Comment: I don't think `br` is supposed to be like this: `</br>`?

Comment: despite the many html tag errors, data.js will load if it's in the same folder as the html file - how do you know the data.js isn't loaded? neither of the functions in data.js are called in the html, so, what do you expect data.js to do

Comment: your `<meta charset="UTF-8">` must be before the `<title>` to get the work also for the title. **Note: this doesn't have nothing to do with your script problem**

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/zfFTdQC.png both files are in the same folder

Comment: Shouldn't he try to call the function first to know  if the script is working or not? Because he said that there is no error in the console it should have 404 not found if the script is not loaded.

Comment: it has error now: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code, it doesn't look like you're calling either of your functions. If you're sure the script isn't loading, the F12 tools will help, as others have suggested in the comments.

Try calling the `startTime()` function at the bottom of your JavaScript file and see if it works:

```
function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
  "Time: " + h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  
  return i;
}
startTime();
```

**Update:** The error mentioned in the comment below is caused by the script executing before the `txt` element exists on the page. Here are two solutions:

1. Move the script to the bottom of the page.

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    <script src="data.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

2. Don't execute the script until the page has loaded. There are a few ways to do this. Here's one:

```
// Instead of this at the end of your script:
startTime();
// Do this:
window.addEventListener('load', startTime);
```

Comment: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: Good! That means you're trying to modify an element before it exists. Which means the script is running. You can either move the <script src="..."></script> to just before the </body> tag, or you can run it in the load event handler.

Comment: What can I do about this?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you properly saved your javascript file. 
Second, open a new page and see if you can access your javascript file from that path.
Third, did you correctly save the file? I suggest you open a new file and save your code properly using the .js extension.

Sample Directory Structure.

```
ParentDirectory/ChildDirectory
../mytemplate.html
../myfunc.js
../othertemplates.html
```

The sample files above are all in the same directory. Setup your structure similarly and test if it works

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript file is loading without error. But you are not calling the function on your JS file so it is not executing and have no effect on html file. Please check your JS code again.

Comment: it has error now: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things wrong here
your mark up has lot of mistakes no proper ending tags
in table you have no thead and tbody

```html
<html>


<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> HTML/CSS: układ strony www w oparciu o elementy HTML5. </title>

    <script src="flexbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="flexbox.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="strona">
        <header class="elementy">
            <img src="zdj/win95.png" alt="Win95" />
            <p>Najlepszy system operacyjny świata...</p>
            <div id="txt"></div>
        </header>

        <nav id="nav_gorny" class="elementy">
            <ol>
                <li class="home"><a href="index.html">Strona główna</a></li>
                <li class="system"><a href="system.html">O systemie</a></li>
                <li class="wymag"><a href="wymagania.html">Wymagania</a></li>
                <li class="galeria"><a href="galeria.html">Galeria</a></li>
            </ol>
        </nav>

        <nav id="nav_lewy" class="elementy">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Strona główna</a></li>
                <li><a href="system.html">O systemie</a></li>
                <li><a href="wymagania.html">Wymagania systemu</a></li>
                <li><a href="galeria.html">Galeria zdjęć Windows95</a></li>
                <li><a href="programy.html">Programy</a></li>
                <li><a href="autor.html">Autor</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>


        <article>
            <section id="sekcja_gorna" class="elementy">
                <p> Wymagania sprzętowe </p>
            </section>
            <section id="sekcja_dolna" class="elementy">

                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Procesor Intel 80386DX 16 MHz</td>
                                <td>Procesor Intel 80486DX 16 MHz</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>4 MB pamięci RAM (8 MB przy OSR2 i późniejsze) </td>
                                <td>8 MB pamięci RAM (16 MB przy OSR2 i późniejsze)</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>50-55 MB wolnego miejsca na dysku</td>
                                <td>50-55 MB wolnego miejsca na dysku</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>VGA (640x480), 16 kolorów</td>
                                <td>SVGA (800x600), 256 kolorów</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Stacja dyskietek 3½" o wysokiej gęstości</td>
                                <td>Stacja dyskietek i napęd CD-ROM</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                </table>

            </section>
        </article>
        <br/>
        <aside class="elementy">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="zdj/auto.jpg">
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="zdj/poz.png">
            </a>
        </aside>
        <br />
        <center>
            <footer class="elementy">
                Copyright © Maciej Śliwiński 4F &nbsp;<a href="kontakt.html"> Kontakt &nbsp;</a> <a href="autor.html"> Autor </a>
            </footer>
        </center>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

This has nothing to do with the scripts
you had lang attribute in the html tag ,which is wrong 
lang attribute goes into meta tag.
It is the problem with the mark up 
I have corrected your markup .
Please check.Hope this helps

Comment: I have just added dummy js files and css files to test ...you can consider changing them